# Spark is returning an empty response when visiting a route when enabling CORS in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, spark-java

Here is my CorsRoute taken directly from the [Spark documentation](http://sparkjava.com/tutorials/cors):

```
class CorsRoute(origin: String, methods: String, headers: String) {
    init {
        options("/*") { request, response ->

            val accessControlRequestHeaders = request.headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers")
            if (accessControlRequestHeaders != null) {
                response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", accessControlRequestHeaders)
            }

            val accessControlRequestMethod = request.headers("Access-Control-Request-Method")
            if (accessControlRequestMethod != null) {
                response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", accessControlRequestMethod)
            }

            "OK"
        }

        before { request, response ->
            response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
            response.header("Access-Control-Request-Method", methods)
            response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers)
            response.type("application/json")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I instance the CorsRoute:

```
abstract class Route {
    init {
        CorsRoute("*","*","*")
    }
}
```

Here is how I start my routes:

```
class RestApiRoutes : Route() {
    fun init() {
        get("/test") {
            req, res -> {
                val obj = JsonObject().addProperty("foo", "bar")
                Gson().toJson(obj).toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I head over to `http://127.0.0.1:4567/test` I receive:

> () -> kotlin.String

Why is the page returning this and not my expected JSON response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
{
    req, res -> {
        val obj = JsonObject().addProperty("foo", "bar")
        Gson().toJson(obj).toString()
    }
}
```

is a lambda which returns a lambda without arguments, and not a `String`. And that inner lambda's `toString` returns `() -> kotlin.String`.

Remove the inner `{}` to fix the problem:

```
{ req, res ->
    val obj = JsonObject().addProperty("foo", "bar")
    Gson().toJson(obj).toString()
}
```

(see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#lambda-formatting for formatting conventions)

Comment: Figured it out but forgot to make an answer, this is what i did - thanks for the reply tho! Marked accepted for future viewers!